# URLSession.shared.dataTask return zero bytes

Tags: json, swift, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

My goal is to call a http service that returns a json to be parsed as an array of NewsModel objects.

I defined a struct like that

```
struct NewsModel: Decodable {
    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var content: String
}
```

and wrote this method in **Service.swift** class:

```
func getNews(pageSize: Int, pageCount: Int, completion: @escaping ([NewsModel]?) -> ()) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "\(Service.baseURLSSMService)/news?pageSize=\(pageSize)&pageCount=\(pageCount)") else {return}

        var retVal = [NewsModel]()

        // Create URLRequest
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        // Set headers and http method
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data,
                error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                    completion(nil)
                    return }
            do{                
                    print("RESPONSE:\(response.debugDescription)")
                    retVal = try
                        JSONDecoder().decode([NewsModel].self, from: dataResponse)
                    completion(retVal)

            } catch let parsingError {
                print("Error", parsingError)
                completion(nil)
            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

I need to call this method from my **HomeViewController**. I used this code in my viewDidLoad:

```
Service.sharedInstance.getNews(pageSize: 10, pageCount: 1) { (news) in

            // I need the first element of the news array   
            // I save it into a global variable 
            self.homeNews = news?.first

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if self.homeNews != nil {
                    self.myLabel.text = self.homeNews?.title
                }
                else {
                    self.myLabel.text = "No data received."    
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run the code, it always happens that the getNews function returns 0 bytes so nothing can be parsed by the JSONDecoder. This is the error message:

> Error dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [],
>   debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.",
>   underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840
>   "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})))

If I call it twice the last time proper values are received. What am I doing wrong? Because I guess I'm doing wrong something but I cannot get it.

**EDIT 1**:

This is a json sample:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2048,
    "title": "title-sample-1",
    "content": "content-sample-1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2047,
    "title": "title-sample-2",
    "content": "content-sample-2"
  }
]
```

**EDIT 2**:

Here is the response.debugDescription

```
RESPONSE:Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x2830a1160> { URL: http://.../news?pageSize=1&pageCount=1 } { Status Code: 400, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    Date =     (
        "Tue, 27 Nov 2018 15:38:38 GMT"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    ); } })
```

Comment: It looks like your JSON doesn't match with your struct. Can you add your JSON please?

Comment: Have you tested your url in a web browser?

Comment: Also `completion(retVal)` needs to be within your do catch block

Comment: @RobertDresler I added a json sample in the EDIT 1 block. But I wonder why the second time the call works if the json doesn't not match my struct...

Comment: add a `completion(nil)` after `print("Error", parsingError)` and  `completion(retVal)` after `retVal = try ...` and remove  `DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(retVal)
            }`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, test in a web browser is OK.

Comment: @LeoDabus I followed your suggestions. Nothing has changed though.

Comment: I know this wouldn’t fix your issue just make your code concise you need to check if your server is returning or not any data

Comment: Actually you are not using the request. Change your url to request in your dataTask call

Comment: @LeoDabus you're right, I did not use request... Now I edited my code by using it but nothing changed.

Comment: if you don't post your url nobody will be able to help you considering the fact you are stating that the data is nil.

Comment: try changing your request http header field `request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059317/how-can-i-fix-error-domain-nscocoaerrordomain-code-3840-no-value-userinfo-n

Comment: @LeoDabus first of all thank you for your patience :) 
I'm working with a local url so nobody can access the content on the internet. Via browser I always check that data is not empty. And as I wrote before if I call the service for the second time immediately it returns some data. So I guess I'm getting some error about caching or async calls... I'm getting mad about it. PS: header field changed.

Comment: @Rob I also posted the response... Error 400, bad request. 
If I typed some wrong code in my request I'd expect the error raising all the time. Not only the first.

Comment: Your 400 status code is telling you that your request is malformed. The content type of your GET request is _not_ JSON. It’s application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: FYI, HTTP errors, like 400, do not result in error object. You have to cast the `URLResponse` to a `HTTPURLResponse` and then look at its `statusCode`. If it’s not 2xx, then there was some server error.