# Getting Error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.} when Running request.httpMethod = "GET"

Tags: ios, json, http, swift4

I am running one of my function to get notifications from server using access token after Logging in, I am getting error at line  **request.httpMethod = "GET"**. I am beginner to `Swift` can some one please help to modify the code to get rid of error. Let me know if you need more details. Basically this function passes the access token to server and gets the related notifications for the user from server. below I have pasted my code

Detailed Error

> 2019-10-09 12:07:09.697306+0530 facitech_newfile[58366:1505543]
>   [Common] _BSMachError: port 9707; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14)
>   "Unable to insert COPY_SEND" (lldb) Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}

```
func load_notification()
     {
        let Detail = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Detail") as! 
        DetailViewController
        let appdelegatenew = UIApplication.shared.delegate
        appdelegatenew?.window??.rootViewController = Detail

       let accesstoken: String? = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "tokennew")
        print(accesstoken)
       let myUrl = URL(string:"https://communitymgmtapi.azurewebsites.net/api/notification/")
       var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
         print(accesstoken)
        request.httpMethod = "GET" //compose Query Sgtring
        request.addValue("Bearer \(accesstoken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data: Data?,response:URLResponse?,error:Error?) in
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:.mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let subj = parseJSON["subject"] as? String
                        let msg = parseJSON["body"] as? String
                        print(subj)
                        print(msg)
                    }

                }
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }



        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Instead you can use the popular third party `Alamofire` to call api.

Comment: You can find some help on this question stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39059317/how-can-i-fix-error-domain-nscocoaerrordomain-code-3840-no-value-userinfo-n

Comment: I have used similar code and added addvalue . but still no luck